# Unable to compile swf for GrindPlayer videoplayer

Tags: java, video-player

I am stuck with code of GrindPlayer. I am tring to build it on my computer using the directions given on link:

https://github.com/kutu/GrindPlayer

But it is not forming swf file in build folder. I have fixed version in flex-config as well. But still swf is not generating.

Rightnow it shows a error screen for few seconds on running Btach file grind_player
: cannot find Java Runtime Environment.

Even though I already have jre in my system.

Kindly suggest!!

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement the environment variable JAVA_HOME, with the value of the path of Java jdk, in my case C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_30.